# Set unt price based on total units ordered

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where the unit price is related to the total number of units you order. There are three scenarios:

1. Total units are less than the minimum quantity. Unit price should set to the smallest quantity value.
2. Total units is within the listed unit range. Unit price set appropriately.
3. Total units are greater than the total quantity. Set unit price to the largest quantity value.

The example below only works for scenario 1 and 2.

```
prices = [
  {
    quantity: '50',
    price: '2.5'
  },
  {
    quantity: '100',
    price: '2.45'
  },
  {
    quantity: '250',
    price: '2.4'
  },
  {
    quantity: '500',
    price: '2.35'
  },
  {
    quantity: '1000',
    price: '2.3'
  }
];

// Set unit price to the minimum price
let unitPrice = unit.unitDetails.prices ? unit.unitDetails.prices[0].price : 0;

for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
  if (Number(totalUnits) <= Number(prices[i].quantity)) {
    unitPrice = prices[i].price;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `break` in your loop and flip the equality.
This will take care of Scenarios 2 and 3 for you.

```
for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
  if (Number(totalUnits) >= Number(prices[i].quantity)) {
    unitPrice = prices[i].price;
  }
}
console.log(unitPrice);
```